# How to store string as array in database column using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.1

This question is asked many times on SO. The main problem is nothing got fits into my situation.

Case is, I am not able to store typed content as array in database column.

**text_field whose code is:**

```
= text_field_tag 'product[keywords][]', @product.keywords, class: 'tab-input
product_keywords'
```

**In controller strong parameters are:**

```
params.require(:product).permit(:id, :name, :keywords => [])
```

**Jquery code that is not not removing value upon deletion when typed wrong value but it add commas after each element as I want to take commas seperated value in one column.**

```
  $(document).on 'keyup', '.product_keywords', ->
    keyword = @value.replace(/(\w)[\s,]+(\w?)/g, '$1, $2')
    if keyword != @value
      @value = keyword
    return
```

**model code:**

```
serialize :keywords, Array
```

**migration code:**

```
class AddKeywordsToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :products, :keywords, :text
  end
end
```

So, if someone writes, abc and hit space a comma is added in the end. after three typed words it will look like:

```
abc, dbx, she
```

now I want to store it as array in column but its not storing properly. 
it stores as:

```
["abc, dbx, she"]
```

Also please can anybody tell me the best cases to handle these cases?
Plus best practices to deal with such cases using ruby so I will learn it for future?

Comment: You can split string & use it as array by using `str.split(/\s*,\s*/)` which will remove leading & ailing whitespaces also

Comment: @ray at what stage I need to do this please?

Comment: check answer posted, whether it work

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a custom serializer as shown [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize). So instead of:

```
serialize :keywords, Array
```

You might do somewhat like:

```
serialize :keywords, KeywordSerializer
```

And somewhere in `helpers`:

```
class KeywordSerializer 
  def self.dump(what)
    what.join(", ")
  end
  def self.load(what)
    what.split(/\s*,\s*/)
  end
end
```

Comment: Should I take the keywords without adding custom commas in the end of each keyword now?

Comment: It’s up to you and the desired implementation of both `dump` and `load`; I just showed the generic receipt.

Comment: This is real good one, but I am getting nil for what inside `load` method, why?

Comment: @ray I have no idea.

Comment: @ray Same here.

Answer (score 0):

Passing array elements using single form tag is not possible to pass as a array and passing array as a string, you need to process it near white-listing your params,

```
permitted_params = params.require(:product).permit(:id, :name, :keywords => [])
permitted_params[:keywords] = permitted_params[:keywords][0].split(/\s*,\s*/)
```