# How to convert string from array field and save it as array in db column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am not able to store array in database column.

**text_field:**

```
= text_field_tag 'product[keywords][]', @product.keywords, class: 'tab-input
product_keywords'
```

**controller params:**

```
params.require(:product).permit(:id, :name, :keywords => [])
```

**model:**

```
serialize :keywords, Array
```

**migration:**

```
class AddKeywordsToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :products, :keywords, :text
  end
end
```

So, if someone writes, **abc mbc csx** and hit submit it should save in db column as array like below:

```
["abc", "mbc", "csx"]
```

now I want to store it as array in column but its not storing properly. 
it stores as:

```
["abc mbc csx"]
```

Also what are the best practices to deal with these cases?

Comment: In your model, `serialize :keywords, Array`, did you try just  `serialize :keywords` without the Array?

Comment: What do your submitted parameters look like?

Comment: @AadityaMaheshwari still returns `["voip man cat"]`

Comment: @jvillian they look like: `["voip man cat"]` or `"keywords"=>["voip man cat"]`

Comment: @LearningROR I assume you already tried restarting the server & rails console after editing the model?

Comment: @AadityaMaheshwari yes many times upon each single change. :)

Comment: Presumably, the answers to your prior [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984862/how-to-store-string-as-array-in-database-column-using-ruby-on-rails) didn't work. Did you try `KeywordSerializer`, as suggested? And why is it you think you can store an `array` in a `text` column? `array` != `text`.

Comment: @jvillian well, I have tried all answers from my old question but none of them worked as they should. I was ended with some errors in the end.
Also during finding here and there I found on many blogs and on SO that storing array this way worked well.

Comment: @LearningROR For the migration try this: `add_column :products, :keywords, :string, array: true, default: []`.
Also, did you try not specifying keywords as an array in your controller params and still use serialize?

Comment: @jvillian The main problem I faced during the whole time is lack of proper way to deal this particular case. Mostly people suggest to create new model, migration and all but this is something that do not need to create all those. Some said create text field and do array serialize. some suggest jsonb.

Comment: @AadityaMaheshwari I tried both cases just now and they saved the data as empty array in the column.`{}`

Comment: @AadityaMaheshwari `"keywords"=>"void wan lan"` and in controller no array params, in model no array serialize just posted data `lan man voip` and it saved as empty array

Comment: @LearningROR In the model, keep the serialize but in controller try `params.require(:product).permit(:id, :name, :keywords)`.

Comment: @AadityaMaheshwari  returned: `can't serialize `keywords`: was supposed to be a Array, but was a String. -- "void wan lan"

`

Comment: @LearningROR this is getting too long for comments; head in to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44914/ruby-sometimes-on-rails

Comment: @AadityaMaheshwari Sure brother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this use case:

Removed serialize array from model. Post without array params.

Post with commas on the front end. On the view, use `.join(',')`

Answer (score 0):

You can keep storing it as a text with a separator like a "," for example. And you convert it to an array when you read it as the following:

```
keywords = Product.find(id).keywords.split(",")
```